# click is undefined (unmuting stream on page load)

Tags: javascript

A stream I set up has an autoplay feature through its streaming provider, but it only applies to video. Audio (on the right channel) [remains muted](http://thecanarytest.com/#/) until the user clicks unmute. I want the audio to autoplay as well.

I figure simulating a click on the mute button on page load would do what I want. But doing this in console gives a  `click is undefined` error. Why is this?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-mute-control").click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you probably should do

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click
```

unlike the `document.getElementById` which returns one item